# differences between using of first and firstly

Tags: grammar

When Eva was **first** diagnosed with diabetes she was twenty.

When Eva was **firstly** diagnosed with diabetes she was twenty.

Which one is grammatically correct to say and as I know both first and firstly we can use as an adverb.

Comment: Related: **1** [First, Second, Third, and Finally](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174847/first-second-third-and-finally) and **2** [First, … Secondly, … &c](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/273525/first-secondly-c) Worth reading Sven Yarg's exhaustive answer.

Comment: also related: **3** [How is the predicate of the verb 'to diagnose' formed?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254426/how-is-the-predicate-of-the-verb-to-diagnose-formed) and **4** [Is the correct usage of “Diagnose (verb)” losing its ground?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10021/is-the-correct-usage-of-diagnose-verb-losing-its-ground)

Comment: So who's to say which sentence is grammatically correct? But push comes to shove, I would opt for the first one.

Comment: Generally, "firstly" is only used when one wishes to be a bit ostentatious.

Answer (score 0):

Both appear to be correct as adverb form of *firstly* appears to be a synonym of adverb form of *first*.
https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/firstly

However, I saw only *first* being used the way you used it. The second form using *firstly* looks clumsy to me but it may just be that I am not used to it.

I only saw *firstly* used in the sense of "*in the first place*".

If you have no specific reason to prefer *firstly*, perhaps you should prefer using *first* to avoid any confusion.